# Setup JMeter proxy to record activities on a local web application

Tags: proxy, jmeter

I'm new to JMeter and I want to load test a local web application recording test case with JMeter proxy.

I've first followed instruction here http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf and all worked fine.

Than:

- I launched my web application, say `http://localhost:8080/my-application`
- Setup JMeter web proxy on port 8081
- Added an HTTP Request Default to a Thread Group
- Addea a Recording Controller
- Invoked  `curl -X GET http://localhost:8081/my-application/index.html`

I obtain:

- Request are recorded but with wrong parameters, eg. **https** instead of http
- I don't get the requested page with curl, but the exception: `org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: URI does not specify a valid host name: https:///my-application/index.html/my-application/index.html`
- The parameters I've specified in Http Request Default seems to be ingnored? I placed configuration element under HTTP Proxy Server, and tried many settings.

What's going wrong? I missed some basic configuration? I'm using JMeter Proxy in the wrong manner?

Answer (score 6):

Firefox by default does not allow localhost or 127.0.0.1 to be proxied.

You have to modify a setting in about:config

change **network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost** to **true**

Answer (score 5):

Firefox default setting will bypass "localhost, 127.0.0.1" from proxy so your JMeter still not able to record it. You have to empty the "No Proxy for" field, by removing the "localhost, 127.0.0.1". Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

Go To Browser LAN Settings

Make sure "Bypass proxy server for local addresses" is unchecked so that request will hit JMeter proxy server.

Answer (score 1):

Simple steps to be followed for recording in jmeter:

> 1. open ur jmeter (contains testplan and workbench in default)
> 2. add a threadgroup
> 3. add “http request defaults” whic is under config( change the server name i.ethe site u need to record)
> 4. add “http proxy server (workbench-rightclick-non testing elements-http proxy server)change the default port 8080 to
>      someother(eg 9090)
> 5. start the proxy server
> 6. change the browser settings to manual setup with 9090 port and localhost

http://brittoc.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/jmeter-recording-steps/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Apache's own tutorial on this, it is located here...
[JMeter Proxy Tutorial](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)

I see that you say you have followed it, but it may have changed since you used it as some of your steps do not match the current tutorial. Perhaps your version had a bug or you missed a step, because I just double checked it 5 minutes ago and it worked for me and I don't see some of the steps you are talking about above.

I realize you have specific questions about specific errors that you are concerned with, but based on your current unfamiliarity with the process in general, I would abandon the curl part, and just do the basic proxy recording as Apache describes it to get a better general understanding, then take it from there.

The only caveat I would add to their tutorial, they have you create filters to only record certain types of actions, I actually leave those out so it will record all actions, then I just clean it up later.

This way you don't miss anything that could potentially be causing lag because that type of resource was filtered out.

*** Now, one thing in your original question, you can try if you have no intention of doing the tutorial, try the browser, not curl, and setup your browser to use a proxy, and make sure the port matches the one you specify in jmeter on the proxy node.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple to configure. Please have a look to the attached screenshot.[image]