# Jmeter - Recording test cases through port 8080 - timeout error

Tags: apache, jmeter, ports

I have created below setup in Jmeter to run recorded test cases.

1. Added Thread Group to test plan.
2. Added HTTP Request Defaults to thread group (in path section i have given url as 'http://localhost:8044')

   **note**: 'http://localhost:8044' is the url which i want to launch on firefox.
3. Added Recording controller to thread group

**In workbench**
    Added HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder (In port section i have given 8080 as port no)

Now when I recorded test cases and played the test plan- test samples are failing with the following error.

**Error**:
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection timed out: connect

Running this setup in virtual machine.I have tried with some other ports like 7070,8055,8044 but still getting same error.

Not sure where the issue is. Can any one please help me on this.

Comment: Port `8044` is not port `8080`...

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup the proxy in the browser also with same port that you mentioned in `Test Script Recorder`

1. 8044 port - is in which server is listening (HTTP Sampler port)
2. 8080 port - is in which proxy server is listening (Test Script Recorder port)

Both are different. we need to configure proxy server port (which we specified in Test Script Recorder) in the browser setting also.

Note: If 8080 is already taken by some other process in your machine, try different port.

**Setting up proxy in Firefox:**

Options -> Advanced -> Network tab -> Settings button related to Connection -> enter port in `Manual Proxy Configuration`).

Follow the steps mentioned here:

1. https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

Comment: Hi Naveen, I have done proxy setup in firefox browser. There under Manual Proxy Configuration I have added port 8080 as localhost. Still I see the error. I have tried with other ports like 7070,8055 etc...

Comment: Is recording successfully records HTTP requests? If the error is displayed during replay, then you must turn off the proxy server in `test script recorder`. Both Jmeter & Server in virtual machine?

Comment: Naveen, Yes I can see samples are generated under Recording controller. In each sample I see port as 443.In fact I have set 8080 in test script recorder. Is this ok? and to test the recorded url  I copied the complete url from the sample and entered on firefox, it says after loading 'The proxy server is refusing connections'. I tried turning off test script recorder still seeing same error. Yes the whole setup is in virtual machine.

Comment: I suggest start from beginning again. follow the steps https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf. you can't specify `8080` in Test script recorder, as it is server port but not proxy server port.

Comment: With proxy setting, any url manually entered on firefox its throwing msg as 'The proxy server is refusing connections'. But when I changed from proxy setting to automatically detect settings urls working fine. I need to check why proxy server is refusing.

Comment: No need of going here and there. pls follow the steps mentioned in the reference URL. I think you have not started `Test Script Recorder`. Remember, to start recording, 1. start test script recorder with some port 2. configure browser proxy settings with same port. thats it. now perform the operations in browser that you want record.

Comment: Followed the procedure and tested. Its working well outside virtual machine. Inside its not working and seeing the same issue.

Comment: Ok. what is the issue? both Jmeter and server in the same machine?

Comment: Yes. Both are in virtual machine. I have to setup everything inside. Outside its fine. Inside I see the connection timeout issue. Is this anything to do with firewall setting? or any other settings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135664/discussion-between-naveen-and-sanjay-pujari).

Answer (score 0):

1. Add Thread Group to test plan.
2. Add Transaction controller to thread group
3. Add HTTP(S)Test Script Recorder to workbench

In `HTTP(S)Test Script Recorder` set global setting port to `8080`,in target controller select the `transaction controller` in which you want to record the test click on start button before clicking start button you have to set proxy to record the script to do that go to `firefox-option-Advanced-Network-Connection` click on setting- select manual proxy config-in HTTP proxy give `localhost and port 8080` and check the use this proxy server for all protocols .

This works for me.Check if `8080` port used by another process to do so in cmd type `netstat -an`

Comment: The issue is because of the 'http://localhost:8044' url which is added in HTTP Request defaults. Somehow recorder is not recording from this url. Other urls work fine.Now the scenario is                                           1) 8044 port - is in which server is listening (HTTP Sampler port)
2) 8080 port - is in which proxy server is listening (Test Script Recorder port)         Question: Will recorder work ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. Recording was not happening because of this.

Firefox default setting will bypass "localhost, 127.0.0.1" from proxy so your JMeter still not able to record it. You have to empty the "No Proxy for" field, by removing the "localhost, 127.0.0.1". Hope this will help.

I removed localhost, 127.0.0.1 from the no proxy field in firefox.

Got the fix from the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/37776363/4715839

Thanks all for sharing your comments.