# Why Jmeter is not recording application url starting Localhost?

Tags: jmeter

I have an application installed on my machine for learning purposes. Its URL is http://Localhost:8080/*****. JMeter fails to record the requests whenever I use the URL above. If I replace "localhost" with the machine IP, JMeter records without any issues. Loadrunner can record both URLs.

Is it a bug or is the JMeter proxy setting designed in that way?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter doesn't filter [loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost#Loopback) URLs, however you browser can do this, at least latest [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) does:

[image]

As per [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter/) article you might also need to install [Microsoft Loopback Adapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/cc708322(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

[image]

And last, but not the least, the application, browser and JMeter might be looking into different protocols: [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) and [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6), you need to ensure that your `localhost` hostname resolves into the same IP address for all 3 components.

Answer (score 2):

Latest version of Firefox by default does not allow localhost or 127.0.0.1 to be proxied.

After searching a lot online, finally the following steps worked for me:

1. Enter **about:config** in the Firefox URL bar
2. Search for config **network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost**  using the search box and toggle its value to **true**

Now try recording scripts in Jmeter from localhost related webpages.

**Note:**

1. I am using **Firefox 80.0.1 (64-bit)** and **Apache JMeter 5.3**
2. I found reference from [Setup JMeter proxy to record activities on a local web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501559/setup-jmeter-proxy-to-record-activities-on-a-local-web-application)

Please find the about:config page for Firefox browser below.